# Error when trying to cast double to char *

Tags: c

My project is to scan an address space (which in my case is 0x00000000 - 0xffffffff, or 0 - (2<sup>32</sup>)-1) for a pattern and return in an array the locations in memory where the pattern was found (could be found multiple times).

Since the address space is 32 bits, i is a double and max is pow(2,32) (also a double).

I want to keep the original value of i intact so that I can use that to report the location of where the pattern was found (since actually finding the pattern requires moving forward several bytes past i), so I want temp, declared as char *, to copy the value of i.  Then, later in my program, I will dereference temp.

```
double i, max = pow(2, 32);
char *temp;
for (i = 0; i < max; i++) 
{
   temp = (char *) i;       
   //some code involving *temp    
}
```

The issue I'm running into is a double can't be cast as a char *.  An int can be; however, since the address space is 32 bits (not 16) I need a double, which is exactly large enough to represent 2^32.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Can you use `uint32_t` instead?

Comment: You can use a `long` or even a `long long`.

Comment: Also, you'll get an Access Violation (aka "segfault") almost immediately, since not all memory addresses are accessible. ;)

Comment: Plus, if you're hoping to poke around in the memory of other programs, that won't work. Each process can only see their own memory (plus a bit of shared stuff). Unless you're maybe on some embedded system or something else exotic?

Comment: @George - a segfault happens when a program tries to access a memory address it shouldn't (generally, the OS hasn't allocated actual memory to that address). If this program tries to access ALL addresses, guess what will happen sooner or later?

Comment: @Vilx- I have a handler that takes care of segfaults.

Comment: @George - note: I'm talking about typical desktop/mobile OS'es. That includes Windows, Linux, Android, iOS, OSX. If you're on DOS or an embedded system or something else exotic - that's a different story.

Comment: @clueless_c_programmer - That's good, but if you go accessing memory byte-by-byte, you'll be spending most of your time there. Memory access permissions are set per-page (4KB usually, but check with the OS to be safe). If you segfault on a page, then you can safely skip to the next page. Anyways, what OS are you using and what are you trying to accomplish? This is an odd thing to do, and chances are there is a better way of doing what you're trying to.

Comment: @Vilx- Right, I should have mentioned- the handler takes care of skipping pages too, so we avoid that.  Ubuntu 16.04.05 LTS.  It's an assignment for school- we need to scan an address space and find a pattern.

Comment: Converting `double` to pointer is simply not defined by the C standard, for good reasons. It is simply the wrong type for what you are trying to do. The correct type would be `intptr_t`, if it exists. This gives you an integer type that has the same width as pointers. But wait, why do you even need an integer type and can't iterate trough the pointer? And then there is this little thing that accessing pointers that do not point to an object is undefined ... oh well there is so much wrong here.

Comment: I don't know where you got the idea that a `double` is "exactly large enough to represent 2^32".  It's usually quite a bit bigger than that.  Meanwhile, nowadays it usually _is_ a safe assumption that `unsigned int` can represent all values from 0 to 2^32 – 1.  Unless you're using DOS,  but why would you do that anymore?

Comment: @zwol in fact, if he was using DOS, he'd be in real mode, which can't possibly have 4GB of RAM

Comment: perhaps my understanding of virtual memory is fuzzy... Is this is user space? If so, I don't understand how this would even be possible. Anytime OP tries to access a memory page not owned by his process, it will segfault, no? Unless this pattern he's looking for is owned by his process, can it even be found?

Comment: @yano I suspect he has not gotten far enough to trip over that problem, but yes.

Comment: I think your only hope is to be root, `mmap` `/dev/mem`, and hope your kernel was compiled with the [`CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM`](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/STRICT_DEVMEM.html) flag disabled.. or recompile your kernel with that flag disabled.. or move to kernel space.

Comment: @yano that is in fact the case and I am well aware of that.  I have a handler that takes care of segfaults.

Comment: @DYZ using long or long long is warning be about overflow in implicit constant conversion on the pow(2,32);

Comment: Perhaps your real problem is that you don't realize you shouldn't be using `pow` in the first place? Instead write `((uint32_t)((1ull << 32) - 1))` or `UINT32_MAX`.  (Keep in mind that unsigned types only go up to 2^N **– 1** where N is the bit width.)

Comment: @clueless_c_programmer: Don't use floating point types at all if you deal with addresses. Not clear what you want to accomplish, but even if we ignore the floating point issue, it looks like something half-baked. What do you want to accomplish other than invoking undefined behaviour?

Comment: @zwol: Or use a `do ... while ( i );` loop  with `uint32_t`.

Comment: Ah. I see the problem. You've tried to cast a `double` to a `char*`. You should never, ever do that.

Answer (score 4):

In C, `double` and `float` are not represented the way you think they are; this code demonstrates that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union _DI
{
    double d;
    int i;
} DI;

int main()
{
    DI di;
    di.d =  3.00;
    printf("%d\n", di.i);
    return 0;
}
```

You will not see an output of `3` in this case.

In general, even if you could read other process' memory, your strategy is not going to work on any modern operating system because of virtual memory (the address space that one process "sees" doesn't necessarily (in fact, it usually doesn't) represent the physical memory on the system).

Answer (score 3):

Never use a floating point variable to store an integer. Floating point variables make approximate computations. It would happen to work in this case, because the integers are small enough, but to know that, you need intimate knowledge of how floating point works on a particular machine/compiler and what range of integers you'll be using. Plus it's harder to write the program, and the program would be slower.

C defines an integer type that's large enough to store a pointer: `uintptr_t`. You can cast a pointer to `uintptr_t` and back. On a 32-bit machine, `uintptr_t` will be a 32-bit type, so it's only able to store values up to 2<sup>32</sup>-1. To express a loop that covers the whole range of the type including the first and last value, you can't use an ordinary for loop with a variable that's incremented, because the ending condition requires a value of the loop index that's out of range. If you naively write

```
uintptr_t i;
for (i = 0; i <= UINTPTR_MAX; i++) {
    unsigned char *temp = (unsigned char *)i;
    // ...
}
```

then you get an infinite loop, because after the iteration with `i` equal to `UINTPTR_MAX`, running `i++` wraps the value of `i` to 0. The fact that the loop is infinite can also be seen in a simpler logical way: the condition `i <= UINTPTR_MAX` is always true since all values of the type are less or equal to the maximum.

You can fix this by putting the test near the end of the loop, before incrementing the variable.

```
i = 0;
do {
    unsigned char *temp = (unsigned char *)i;
    // ...
    if (i == UINTPTR_MAX) break;
    i++;
} while (1);
```

Note that exploring 4GB in this way will be extremely slow, if you can even do it. You'll get a segmentation fault whenever you try to access an address that isn't mapped. You can handle the segfault with a signal handler, but that's tricky and slow. What you're attempting may or may not be what your teacher expects, but it doesn't make any practical sense.

To explore a process's memory on Linux, read `/proc/self/maps` to discover its memory mappings. See [my answer on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux) for some sample code in Python.

Note also that if you're looking for a pattern, you need to take the length of the whole pattern into account, a byte-by-byte lookup doesn't do the whole job.

Comment: One could also skip `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)` bytes every time the signal handler fires.  It would still be slower (probably much slower) than parsing `/proc/self/maps`, but it would avoid having to parse `/proc/self/maps` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Ahh, a school assignment. OK then.

```
uint32_t i;
for ( i = 0; i < 0xFFFFFFFF; i++ )
{
    char *x = (char *)i;
    // Do magic here.
}

// Also, the above code skips on 0xFFFFFFFF itself, so magic that one address here.
// But if your pattern is longer than 1 byte, then it's not necessary
// (in fact, use something less than 0xFFFFFFFF in the above loop then)
```

Comment: My compiler (gcc) isn't liking the uint32_t type:

 error: unknown type name ‘uint32_t’

Am I forgetting to import a library?

Comment: @clueless_c_programmer You need `#include <stdint.h>` to use `uint32_t`.

Comment: I tried implementing exactly what you have above- the loop never ends.  The numbers go all the way up to 0xfffffffe and then it just starts back from 0 again.

Comment: That's... odd. It shouldn't do that, as far as I'm aware. Perhaps there's something else in your code that causes this? If you make just a bare loop - `for ( i = 0; i < 0xFFFFFFFF; i++);` - does that become infinite too?

Comment: @Vilx- bare loop with nothing but a printf to check the value of i is infinite too

Comment: @clueless_c_programmer - That's weird. It terminates for me. Can you maybe share your whole code somewhere?

Comment: @clueless_c_programmer Are you sure you typed `i < 0xFFFFFFFF` and not `i <= 0xFFFFFFFF`?  Vix's loop is infinite with `<=`, but not with `<`.

Comment: @zwol - Well, he says above that "The numbers go all the way up to 0xfffffffe and then it just starts back from 0 again." Which is odd, it means that 0xFFFFFFFF was skipped. How?

Answer (score 2):

The cast of a `double` to a pointer is a constraint violation - hence the error.

> A floating type shall not be converted to any pointer type.  C11dr §6.5.4 4

---

To scan the entire 32-bit address space, use a `do` loop with an *integer* type capable of the [0 ... 0xFFFFFFFF] range.

```
uint32_t address = 0;
do {
  char *p = (char *) address;
  foo(p);
} while (address++ < 0xFFFFFFFF);
```

Comment: Same issue as one of the other suggestions- the loop never ends.  I print out the numbers to check for sure, and they go all the way up to 0xffffffff before starting back from scratch again.

Comment: @clueless_c_programmer The answer _does not_ "starting back from scratch again".  Perhaps you mis-transcribed or changed it?